# Change of basis from monomial basis to Chebyshev basis of polynomials

Tags: polynomials

I have a certain multivariate polynomial (in 4 variables) written in terms of monomials, and I would like to change the basis into Chebyshev orthogonal basis.
Is there any function to do that?

Comment: Can be done with `PolynomialReduce`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: I'm having trouble, I tried `f = Sum[RandomInteger[{-5, 5}] x^k, {k, 0, 5}];
b = Table[ChebyshevT[k, x], {k, 0, 5}];
PolynomialReduce[f, b, x]` and it's just giving $a_1$ as the original polynomial. Am I doing something dumb?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Try defining each Chebyshev polynomial as a new variable, using `b = Table[y[k] - ChebyshevT[k, x], {k, 0, 5}];`. Then see what `PolynomialReduce` produces.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Hm, still having trouble understanding. With randomly generated polynomial `5 - 3 x + 3 x^2 + 2 x^3`, the output by `PolynomialReduce` is `{{0, 3 - 2 x^2 + x (-3 - 2 y[1]) - 3 y[1] - 2 y[1]^2, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
 5 - 3 y[1] + 3 y[1]^2 + 2 y[1]^3}`, but I don't see how that gives the correct answer of Chebyshev polynomial coefficients, which is supposed to be `{13/2, -(3/2), 3/2, 1/2, 0}`.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Ah. Yes, you are getting a "correct" result in terms of the polynomial rewrite, it's just not a useful result (it involves powers of `y[1]`, which is `x`, which is useless). If I get something worked out I'll post.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Here it is. `In[210]:= SeedRandom[1111];
poly = Sum[RandomInteger[{-5, 5}]*x^k, {k, 0, 5}]
b = Table[y[k] - ChebyshevT[k, x], {k, 0, 5}];

Out[211]= -4 - 2 x + 5 x^2 + 2 x^3 - 4 x^4 + 2 x^5

In[213]:= newpoly = Fold[Last[PolynomialReduce[#1, #2, x]]
   &, poly, Reverse[b]]

Out[213]= 1/8 (-24 + 6 y[1] + 4 y[2] + 9 y[3] - 4 y[4] + y[5])

In[214]:= Expand[newpoly - poly /. y[j_] :> ChebyshevT[j, x]]

Out[214]= 0`